# Angularjs popover nglick does not trigger at second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

My problem is I create a popover for controlling the element's width and offset.

Here is the screenshot for better understanding.

**However, the problem is when first click the element (for example: Description1 ), the popover pops up and the ng-click of the four arrows work. But second time click the element, the popover still comes, but the ng-click of the four arrows does not works anymore!**

Here is part of the html code:

```
 <div id="sortable" ng-repeat="object in arrayForShow">
            <div ng-show="checkType(object)">
              <div ng-switch on="getKeyValue(object)">
                <div ng-switch-when="default">
                    <div ng-class="classGenerate(object)" class="well nomargin" id="resizable" pop-over-width-offset argument='object' addwidth='addWidth(object)' decreasewidth='decreaseWidth(object)' addoffset='addOffset(object)' decreaseoffset='decreaseOffset(object)'>
                      {{object.default}}
                    </div>
```

**pop-over-width-offset** is an directive, and pass **object** into it and bind four method: addWidth, addOffset, decreaseOffset, which are in the controller.

The directive part code:

```
app.directive "popOverWidthOffset", ($templateCache, $compile)->
    restrict: 'A',
    controller: 'CustomiseFormCtrl'
    scope: {
        argument: '='
        addwidth: '&'
        decreasewidth: '&'
        addoffset: '&'
        decreaseoffset: '&'
    }
    link: (scope, element, attrs)->
        content = $templateCache.get('angular/templates/popOverCustomisationChangeWidthOffset.html')
        scope.$watch 'content', ()->
            popOverContent = $compile(content)(scope)
            options = {
                content: popOverContent,
                placement: "top",
                html: true,
                trigger: "click"
            }
            $(element).popover(options)
        , true
```

And the template url code is as follows:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a class="btn btn-link" ng-click="addwidth(argument)">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up">
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <a class="btn btn-link">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up" ng-click="addoffset(argument)">
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="form-group" width="40px;">
                <input class="form-control" ng-model="argument.position[1]" style="text-align: center;">
            </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td class="form-group" width="40px;">
                <input class="form-control" ng-model="argument.position[2]" style="text-align: center;">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a class="btn btn-link" ng-click="decreasewidth(argument)">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down">
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <a class="btn btn-link">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" ng-click="decreaseoffset(argument)">
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: The more you use words like URGENT, ASAP etc..the more you're preventing users from helping you

Comment: @asprin But really need help and advice

Comment: Being a baby will not get you the help and advice you want. Stop it.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```js
popOverContent = $compile(content)(scope)
```

with this:

```js
popOverContent = function() {
  return $compile(content)(scope);
};
```

;)